How to display value correctly between 2 tables
I have two tables that I'm trying to show a flat view from. I have table A with a Product Code and Table B with that Code and a column of Status codes (Done, NotDone, InProcess). That status has a date/time associated with its product code. When I join on the code, I get all the codes regardless if they have a datetime or not. How do I display Product Code, DoneDateTime, InProcessDateTime, NotDoneDateTime in their own columns as a single flat view assuming they datetime code exists?
Table A



ProdCode




111


222


223



TableB



ProdCode
Status
Date




111
Done
1/10/01


111
Start
1/1/01


222
Done



222
Start
1/2/01



Desired View



ProdCode
Start Date
Done Date




111
1/1/01
1/10/01


222
1/2/01





Please format your sample data, to include the sample dates from tableB that you want to see in your desired view.

Can you show us what you've done so far?

Why would tableB have a null date for "done" status? Wouldn't that row simply not be there?

You can use conditional aggregation as one method. I think it's better to show all prodCodes, even those which haven't started, hence the left join. Or would you not want to see prodCode 223? If not, then change LEFT to INNER.
select 
 a.prodCode, 
 max(case when b.status = 'Start' then Date end) as start_date, 
 max(case when b.status = 'Done' then Date end) as end_date
from 
 tableA a
left join 
 tableB b
  on a.prodCode = b.prodCode
group by a.prodCode
order by 1




prodCode
start_date
end_date




111
2001-01-01
2001-01-10


222
2001-01-02
null


223
null
null



fiddle

was not clear how you want to set message. i add extra column
declare @t table (ProdCode int, [Status] varchar(20) , [_Date] Date)
insert into @t values
(111, 'Done','1/10/01'),
(111, 'Start','1/01/01'),
(222, 'Done',null),
(222, 'Start','1/2/01'),
(0, 'Start', NULL)


SELECT s.ProdCode, s.StartDate, e.EndDate,
    msg = case 
            when s.StartDate is null AND e.EndDate is null then 'NOT Started'
            when s.StartDate is not null AND e.EndDate is null then 'in progress'
            else 'DONE' end
FROM
    (select ProdCode, Status as sStatus, _Date as StartDate 
    From @t 
    Where Status ='Start') s
LEFT JOIN 
    (select ProdCode, [status] as EndEstatus, _Date as EndDate 
    From @t 
    Where Status ='Done') e on s.ProdCode = e.ProdCode





result would be



ProdCode
StartDate
EndDate
msg




111
2001-01-01
2001-01-10
DONE


222
2001-01-02
NULL
in progress


0
NULL
NULL
NOT Started



